# Problems changing EmployeeID for multiple users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We're trying to to do something quite simple, that is changing the `EmployeeID` for multiple users, but are having some issues.

We have a variable `$ke` which contains:

```
EmployeeID  Employee
00000122    username1
00000100    username2
```

We're trying to update the `EmployeeID` with:

```
$username = $ke.Employee
foreach($user in $username) {
   Set-ADUser $user -EmployeeID "$ke.EmployeeID"
}
```

But it's failing with this error:

> Set-ADUser : A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values
> At line:2 char:4
> Set-ADUser $user -EmployeeID '$ke.EmployeeID'
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (username1:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException  
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8322,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
> ```

We also tried using:

```
$username = $ke.Employee

foreach($user in $username) { 
   Set-ADUser $user -EmployeeID $ke.EmployeeID
}
```

> Set-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'EmployeeID'. Specified
> method is not supported.
> At line:2 char:33
> Set-ADUser $user -EmployeeID $ke.EmployeeID
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException  
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
> ```

How would we be able to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right this should be enough:

```
foreach($user in $ke) {
   Set-ADUser $user.Employee -EmployeeID $user.EmployeeID
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was indeed simple.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes we cannot see the forest for the trees. 